# How to read an unknown number of strings and how to sort the strings ordering by length and print in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, character

This is what I wrote, and I really don't know how to determine line[??][MAXLINE]...

The point is:

1. get inputs from stdin(keyboard) but I don't know the number of inputs
2. must use copy()
3. sort by string length(from short to long length!

so if I input

```
I love you
me
too
```

result:

```
me
too
I love you
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "copy.h"

char line[MAXLINE][MAXLINE];
char tmp[MAXLINE];
int main () {
     int len,i,j,k=0;
    while(gets(line)!= NULL){
        i++;//using index
        len=i+1;//save i till null cuz I expect that it could be number of inputs
    }
    for(j=0; j< len-1; j++){
        for(k=j+1; k<len-j-1; k++){
            if (strlen(line[j])>strlen(line[k])){
                copy(line[j],tmp);
                copy(line[j],line[k]);
                copy(tmp,line[k]);
            }   
        }
    }
    for(j=0; j<len;j++){
        printf("%s\n",line[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
 
copy.h
#define MAXLINE 100
void copy(char from[], char to[]);

copy.c
#include <stdio.h>

void copy(char from[], char to[])
{
    int i;

    i=0;
    while ((to[i]=from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: When you say `char line[MAXLINE][MAXLINE]`, that means you can have up to 100 lines, and each line can be up to 100 (really 99) characters long.  That'll work, but it's confusing.  It would be better to do `#define MAXLINES 100` and maybe also `#defien MAXLINELEN 100` and then you can say `char lines[MAXLINES][MAXLINELEN]`.

Comment: If your question is, how can you change it so that instead of being limited to 100 lines, you can accept an arbitrary number of lines, that's a harder problem.  One solution is to use `malloc` and `realloc`.  There are lots of previous questions here on SO (probably at least one per day) showing how to do this.

Comment: It is highly advisable that you ***dump `gets()`*** for `fgets()` It is also suggested to use good spacing between operators and other punctuation.

Comment: thank you! then can I use fgets() like this way?
`while(fgets(line[i],MAXLINE,stdin)!= NULL){`

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `strlen()` and then use one of the [sorting algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/)